# Make new dataframes from one level of a categorical variable in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, factors, levels

```
list2env(split(df, df[,1]), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

I found this code posted earlier, but the problem is that my levels are either numbers or have spaces between words, which I think R does not like. So, the dataframes show up in my global environment, but I can't work with them. When I call functions on them they can't be worked on, and they don't show up in tab complete.

I'm new to R so I'm not sure how to replicate what my data set very well. It's 14,000 observations across 24 variables for collision accidents.

```
Neighborhood <- c("Westboro", "Hintonburg", "Downtown", "Downtown")
AccidentType <- c("Fatal injury", "property damage", "property damage", "injury")

Neighborhood <- as.factor(Neighborhood)
AccidentType <- as.factor(AccidentType)
df <- data.frame(Neighborhood, AccidentType)
```

Pretend I am only interested in property damage and would like an entirely new data frame that shows only the property damage accidents. And that I'd like to retain my old data in its original data frame, too.

Thanks. Sorry I'm so terrible at R.

edit: all the methods in the comments work with the sample data set, but not my actual one for some reason :(

I get this when I try these methods:

```
OttawaCollisions %>% filter(Collision_Classification=="Injury")
 [1] Record                   Location                 X                        Y                       
 [5] Date                     Time                     Environment              Road_Surface            
 [9] Traffic_Control          Collision_Location       Light                    Collision_Classification
[13] Impact_type              Seasons                  Holidays                 LunarPhase              
[17] DayofWeek                Accidents                Longitude                Latitude                
[21] Ward                     WardNumb                 NumText                  TimeCat                 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> View(OttawaCollisions)
> subset(OttawaCollisions, Collision_Classification == "P.D. only")
 [1] Record                   Location                 X                        Y                       
 [5] Date                     Time                     Environment              Road_Surface            
 [9] Traffic_Control          Collision_Location       Light                    Collision_Classification
[13] Impact_type              Seasons                  Holidays                 LunarPhase              
[17] DayofWeek                Accidents                Longitude                Latitude                
[21] Ward                     WardNumb                 NumText                  TimeCat                 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I'm not sure why zero rows are showing up. It makes no sense. I have lots of data (14,000 points) and they are all converted to factors. And they are when I call str() on them. Ugh.

Comment: Just keep them in a single data frame, and filter/subset out the piece you want, when you need it, or just do the `split()` part and pick out the list element you want by name.

Comment: Please show an example? I actually also do need the data frames separated by some of these levels eventually anyways.

Comment: My point is that you actually don't. Any instance where you might want to refer to a stand alone data frame called `data_subset` can be replaced with an inline subset or a reference to a list element from the results of `split()`.

Comment: `df %>% filter(AccidentType=="property damage")` in `dplyr` package will pick out only the rows that meet that condition. Not only will `df` not be changed, but you can pipe that whole line into another command, e.g. `df %>% filter(AccidentType=="property damage") %>% ggplot()  +...`

Comment: In your first example you misspelled "injury".

Comment: A space in a factor level is just another character. R functions do not parse within level names. So the notion the "R does not like spaces" is really not at all well expressed. Also `"injury"` is not the same word as `"Injury"`. Please try to be more precise and less anthropomorphic in your description of programming problems.

Answer (score 1):

To explicit what's said in comments, you could just filter your data.frame :

in base R :

```
subset(df,AccidentType == "property damage")
```

with dplyr :

```
filter(df,AccidentType == "property damage")
```

If filtering was costly and you wanted to make it only once (but it's not if you have 14k rows only) you could split your df in a list:

```
df_list <- split(df,df$AccidentType)
```

Then call `df_list[["property damage"]]`

So you don't need a separate object for each `data.frame` and it wouldn't be recommended.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I edited in a comment. I think something is wrong with my data but I don't know what. I get zero returns for rows.

Comment: Turns out I left a blank character before some of the levels, so the reason nothing would work was because I had to type something like " Injury" instead of "Injury". Ah.